# MKMap don't display Open Street Map tile overlay

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, maps, mkmapview, openstreetmap

I try display OSM tile as layer above Apple map on MKMapView in Xamarin iOS

```
private MKTileOverlay _tileOverlay;
...... 
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
  .....
  MapDelegate _mapDelegate = new MapDelegate ();
  map.Delegate = _mapDelegate;
  .....

  String urlTemplate = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
  _tileOverlay = new MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate);
  _tileOverlay.CanReplaceMapContent = true;
  map.AddOverlay(_tileOverlay, MKOverlayLevel.AboveLabels);

  .....
}
```

and overridden OverlayRenderer in class " MapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate "

```
public override MKOverlayRenderer OverlayRenderer (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {
        if (overlay is MKTileOverlay) 
        {
            var tile = (MKTileOverlay)overlay;
            var renderer = new MKTileOverlayRenderer (tile) {
            };

            return renderer;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Running the application I see a blank layer without OSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of iOS are you running ?

Since [iOS9](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html) Apple's Application Transport Security (ATS) will, by default, **requires** the use of HTTPS.

If you want (or need) to use HTTP then you must edit your `Info.plist` to allow specific (or global) use of HTTP. See Xamarin's [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/) for more details.